Nx monorepo and Vite - multiple versions of same dependency in libs
Currently working on an Nx monorepo package-based React application that's structured roughly as follows:
/apps/myApp
  /package.json
  /vite.config.ts (which extends root-level vite.config.ts file)
/libs
  /myLib1
    /package.json
  /myLib2
    /package.json
package.json
package-lock.json
vite.config.ts

Lets say the root-level package.json has a dependency on somePackage v1.2.3 from npm
But myLib2 specifically needs v1.1.1
If I add these respective versions to the root-level package.json and to the myLib2/package.json files and run npm install - I can see that somePackage v1.2.3 gets installed to the root-level node_modules folder and somePackage v1.1.1 gets installed to the node_modules folder inside myLib2 - which is what I would expect.
When running myApp (which has a dependency on myLib2 using Vite dev server - I am seeing code / components in myLib2 use v.1.2.3 of somePackage when I want it to use v1.1.1.
When running Nx build - myLib2 correctly uses v1.1.1 - this issue is specific to Vite dev server.
When inspecting the code from Chrome Dev Tools - I can see that components inside myLib2 are indeed resolving myLib2 from the root-level node_modules folder.
I'm thinking it's somehow related to how Vite does dependency prebundling but I'm not quite sure how to resolve the issue.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!
Additional info:
vite: 4.3.4
nx: 16.2.2
Root-level vite.config.ts:
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import commonjs from 'vite-plugin-commonjs';
import viteTsConfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import path from 'path';
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, `${process.cwd()}/apps/myApp/env`, '');

  return {
    // vite config
    cacheDir: '../../node_modules/.vite/myApp’,

    build: {
      commonjsOptions: {
        include: [/myApp/, /node_modules/],
      },
    },

    envDir: `${process.cwd()}/apps/myApp/env`,

    esbuild: {
      loader: 'tsx',
      include: [
        'apps/**/*.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)',
        'libs/**/*.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)',
      ],
      exclude: [],
    },

    optimizeDeps: {
      esbuildOptions: {
        target: 'esnext',
        loader: {
          '.js': 'jsx',
          '.ts': 'tsx',
        },
      },
    },

    server: {
      port: 8080,
      host: 'localhost',
      fs: {
        // Allow serving files from two levels up to the project root
        allow: ['../..'],
      },
    },
    preview: {
      port: 8080,
    },

    plugins: [
      react(),
      commonjs({
      }),
      viteTsConfigPaths({
        root: '../../',
      }),
      nodePolyfills({
        include: ['util'],
        globals: {
          Buffer: true,
        },
      }),
    ],
  };
});

Edit: I was able to get it "kind of" working by adding somePackage to an excludes array inside optimizeDeps but a) it feels like I shouldn't need to do this b) we have quite a few packages in this situation (and more possibly in the future) - seems odd I would need to explicitly add each of these packages here.

Having the same issue, not seeing anything in documentation or otherwise. Feels like this is an extremely common use case, and was not an issue in webpack...

Seems like this is a known issue with no resolution in sight: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9948
